# How to load 10000 images in a grid view in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-gridview

I want to load a grid view of thousands of image, as Google do in his "Pictures" app (formerly "Gallery"). But a grid view is too slow, is anything I'm missing to performance a good smooth scroll and preloading of all blocks ? (not images, but the space reserved in the list)

Comment: Possible hint: 10000 images aren't displayed at the same time

Comment: See here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: Why is a grid view too slow? Most likely the way you're populating your grid views is too slow, but we can't know without your code.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine **specifically** where you are slow.